# Matplotlib subplots not happy unpacking

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using a Jupyter notebook and I'd like a grid of subplots that is 6 plots high by 4 plots deep.

Before adding any data or manipulating the plots at all I've tried to run just the following line in isolation:

```
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(6, 4, sharex=True, figsize=(13, 7))
```

It gives this exception:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-66-4b47dbb065be> in <module>()
     12 # fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(13, 7))
     13 
---> 14 f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(6, 4, sharex=True, figsize=(13, 7))
     15 # ax1.plot(x, y)
     16 # ax1.set_title('Sharing Y axis')

ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are trying to create a grid of 6x4 (=24) subplots, but you have only named 2 subplots to catch what is returned from `plt.subplots`, so it is trying to unpack 24 subplots into two variables (`ax1` and `ax2`).

You have a couple of options:

1. Catch all subplot instances in one container, and then index that to access individual subplots:

   ```
   f, axes = plt.subplots(6, 4, sharex=True, figsize=(13, 7))
   axes[0,0].plot(x,y)  # plot on top left subplot
   axes[2,1].plot(x,y)  # plot on subplot in column 3, row 2
   ```
2. Catch all subplots individually:

   ```
   fig, (
         (ax11, ax21, ax31, ax41),
         (ax12, ax22, ax32, ax42),
         (ax13, ax23, ax33, ax43),
         (ax14, ax24, ax34, ax44),
         (ax15, ax25, ax35, ax45),
         (ax16, ax26, ax36, ax46)
        ) = plt.subplots(6, 4, sharex=True, figsize=(13, 7))
   ax11.plot(x,y)  # plot on top left axes
   ax32.plot(x,y)  # plot on subplot in column 3, row 2
   ```